# Dimension of the tangent space of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

can you give some hints for the following exercise?
Thank you.

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field, $X=V(x^2+y^2+z^2-1,x-1)\subset \mathbb A^3_k$.

[(a)] Find the dimension of $X$.

[(b)] Describe the tangent space of $X$ at the point $P=(1,0,0)$. What is its dimension?
The point $P$ is a singular point?

[(c)] Determine all the singular points of $X$.

---

I have done this

[(a)] $X$ is the intersection of the unitary sphere $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb A_k^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}=V(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ with the plane $\Pi=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb A_k^3|x=1\}=V(x-1)$, ie,
$X=V(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\cap V(x-1)=\{(1,0,0)\}\cup V(y^2+z^2)$, 
thus dim $X=1$

[(b)] Let $X=V(F_1,F_2)$, where $F_1(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ and $F_2(x,y,z)=x-1$, then the Jacobian matrix is

$\left(\cfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial a}\right) _{i=1,2, a=x,y,z}(x,y,z)=
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
     2x & 2y & 2z \\
     1   & 0 & 0 \\
     \end{array}
    \right)\Longrightarrow \left(\cfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial a}\right) _{i=1,2, a=x,y,z}(1,0,0)=
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
     2 & 0 & 0 \\
     1   & 0 & 0 \\
     \end{array}\right),$
     and it has rank 1.

Thereforedim $T_pX=3-1=2$.

[(c)] Taking partial derivaties, to $f=y^2+z^2$, we get 
$f_x=0,f_y=2y,f_z=2z$, them the only singular point is $(1,0,0)$

Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: Your $k$ is not $\mathbb{R}$ (which isn't even algebraically closed!). So your (a) and (c) have problems.

Comment: You are right, i am going to edit it

Comment: @Sanchez I have edited it, can you see it please?

Comment: You claim that  $X$ has dimension $2$: that is not true.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for your help. Do you mean that dim $T_pX=2?

Comment: I mean $dim(X)=1$ although $dim T_p(X)=2$ : the discrepancy is due to $P$ being a singular point of $X$.